# Como pasar fichero XML a array en Laravel

Tags: laravel, array, xml

estoy haciendo una aplicacion laravel con la que se puede subir un fichero xml al servidor para insertar sus datos en la base de datos.

El problema de esto es que tengo subido el fichero pero no consigo convertirlo a array para poder manejar sus datos desde laravel, he probado varias librerias pero sin exito. A alguien se le ocurre algo con lo que lo podria hacer?.

He probado las librerias de nathanmac/Parser y orchestra/parser

Answer (score 1):

Bastaría con la extensión SimpleXML, generalmente viene en las instalaciones de PHP, al final sería algo como:

```
$xmlDocument = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);
```

Y de ese documento puedes empezar a pedir los nodos que tienen, recorrerlos, obtener sus atributos y valores.

Mira este manual oficial sobre el uso de esta extensión:

http://php.net/manual/es/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, finalmente lo solucioné combinando un File::get de laravel para leer el fichero subido al servidor y despues la funcion de php simplexml_load_string() para su manejo. De todas formas no estoy seguro de si con la función que sugieres se puede interpretar el XML directamente desde el archivo, lo probaré.